# How are system calls are done when writing Java code or any other language?

Tags: java, c, operating-system

In system programming class, we are told that all system calls are made in c. For example opening a file for reading/writing. Does java run c codes behind?

Comment: Depends on which operation system your running your program on, as the JVM is implemented platform dependently. I guess you could even write a JVM for javascript (if it doesn't exist already)

Comment: Java runs on a virtual machine. The code for the virtual machine can be written in any language, as long as it meets the requirements set forth in the specification for the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). But yes, the JVM (or at least parts of it) are often written in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes java runs C Code behind the scene. Using the native keyword.

For Instance: System.currentTimeMillis() is a Native Method

Here is a good explaination how to use Native code:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-native

Answer (score 1):

System calls are not made in C. They are nearly exclusively done in assembly language or languages like BLISS that give access to hardware instructions.

A system call requires triggering an exception in order to put the processor in a protected mode.